# Is it possible to SSL Proxy an Android Instant App?

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy, android-instant-apps

Is it possible to SSL Proxy network traffic from an Instant App?

I am trying to SSL proxy the Instant App for an application I am developing, but I am unable to SSL Proxy the traffic from the Instant App even when using a device that is less than Nougat.

I have traditionally used CharlesProxy with to verify network calls in the main application. On devices that are Nougat and higher, I can use a cert built into the debug build to enable SSL proxy. On devices lower than Nougat, I can SSL fine with the prod build. Either way, on the main application SSL has worked fine. It is just the Instant App that is giving me an issue.

My current process is:

1) Proxy to my local IP via Charles

2) Download the .pem cert from CharlesProxy website with my device web browser

3) Open Instant App

4) Charles throws "SSL Handshake Failure" on network calls

Comment: It's possible this is not supported in Instant Apps. Do you see anything in the logs? Something like activity not found or security exceptions? Even better, sample code that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787